# Java JDBC storing ResultSet in ArrayList

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, arraylist

I am trying to work myself into using SQLite databases in Java.

(I am also using the [sqlite-jdbc-3.20.0 library](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc), but I think this problem isn't influenced by that.)

I have created some functions I want to use later on to simplify my workflow.
For that I created the class *DBInterface.java*, from which I created an object in my *Main.java* class.

Simplified content of *DBInterface.java*:

```
/**
 * Executes a sql String and returns it's results as ResultSet[].
 *
 * @param sql as String holidng the SQL statement to execute
 * @return ResultSet[] containing the results of the query, or empty ResultSet[] if no results
 */
public ArrayList<ResultSet> excecute(String sql)
{
    if(!isConnected()) return null;
    try
    {
        return getResultSets(statement.execute(sql));
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Main.log(tag, "An SQLException has occured for statement '"+sql+"':");
        Main.log(tag, e);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Returns an array containing all resultSets of the last executed statement.
 *
 * @param isResultSet as boolean defining if the statement resulted in an result set
 * @return
 */
private ArrayList<ResultSet> getResultSets(boolean isResultSet)
{
    ArrayList<ResultSet> results = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {
        int count = 0;
        while(true) {
            if(isResultSet)
            {
                ResultSet set = statement.getResultSet();
                results.add(set);
                /*
                while(set.next())
                {
                    //Here the information can still be retrieved
                    Main.log(tag, ""+set.getString("name")+", row:"+set.getRow());
                }
                */

            }
            else
            {
                if(statement.getUpdateCount() == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Main.log(tag, "Result '"+count+"' is just a count: '"+statement.getUpdateCount()+"'");
            }

            count ++;
            isResultSet = statement.getMoreResults();
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        Main.log(tag, "An SQLException has occured while processing a request:");
        Main.log(tag, e);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Simplified content of *Main.java*:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    [...]

    dbInterface.excecute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
    dbInterface.excecute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (id INTEGER, name STRING(20));");
    dbInterface.excecute("INSERT INTO Users (id, name) VALUES (1, \"Hans\");");
    dbInterface.excecute("INSERT INTO Users (id, name) VALUES (2, \"Peter\");");

    ArrayList<ResultSet> results = dbInterface.excecute("SELECT * FROM Users;");

    log(tag, ""+results.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
    {
        ResultSet set = results.get(i);
        try
        {
            ///*
            while(set.next())
            {
                //TODO Here the information can no longer be retrieved... :(
                Main.log(tag, ""+set.getString("name")+", row:"+set.getRow());
            }
            //*/
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Main.log(tag, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Since from how I understand it is possible in some cases that an SQL query creates multiple ResultSet's, I've though that I will simply add all ResultSet objects to an ArrayList, so I can see when I'm processing the results somewhere else how many ResultSet's exist.
Stranegly though, this doesn't work.
By uncommenting the block in **getResultSets()** in *DBInterface.java* I can confirm that the result set does contain the information.

However, doing the same thing in *Main.java* from the ArrayList, for some reason I can no longer access the information.
I have tested to change the functions to instead return the ResultSet object directly, which did work, however it does not fulfill my goal, since I want to return all possible ResultSet objetcs, not just one.

Comment: are You sure not think 'array list of rows from one ResultSet' ? My preferred structure to return will be `List<Map<String,Object>>`

Comment: `ResultSet` is not something you can pass around and use, since it's associated with a query (i.e. `Statement`) and `Connection`. You need to read it, preferably parse the results into your own domain objects and pass those around.

Comment: Hmmm, then maybe I didn't understand ResultSet correcly.
I thought of it as an object that holds the results of a query, and since it is an object I can pass it (or rather the reference to it) around.
How would I then proceed and store the results of the ResultSet in my own object, if I do not know what it will contain / if there are more then one ResultSet's for the query?

Comment: I suggest you read the JDBC apidoc, result sets are closed if you 1a) execute a new statement on the same `Statement` object, 1b execute any statement on the same connection in auto-commit, 2) close the `Statement`, 3) close the `Connection`, 4) commit/rollback a transaction (and the result set is not holdable over commit), or 5) call `getMoreResults()` on a statement (which you do). Result sets should be processed and closed ASAP, not passed around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a method to convert ResultSet to list, map or class and store the results of ResultSet in your object

Something like this

```
public List resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>(columns);
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
            row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }
        list.add(row);
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Remember to close ResultSet, Statement and Connection when you don't use it**

Closing ResultSet explicitly gives chance to garbage collector to recollect memory as early as possible because ResultSet object may occupy lot of memory depending on query.

Answer (score 1):

Granted, this is much simpler using Spring, but it's good to know how to use plain old JDBC.

Rather than returning a List object, create a Java class to hold the result objects and return those in your list.

You can do this in a method that is specifically designed to return these objects.

For example, if you created a User class, you could do something like this:

```
private static String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users";
...

private List<User> getUsers()
{
    List<User> results = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        while(rs.next()) {
          User aUser = new User();
           aUser.setUserid(rs.getString("USER_ID"));
           aUser.setUserName(rs.getString("USERNAME"));
           ...
         results.add(aUser);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
     // log any exceptions ...
    }
    finally() {
     // always close your JDBC resources - google it
     // example
     try{
        if (statement != null) {
           statement.close();
           statement=null;
        }
      }
      catch(SQLException e) {
        // couldn't close statement
      }
      ...
    }

    return results;
}
```

If you are not using a JDBC [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html), then you have to manage your DB connections yourself - which can be tedious and is (was) a common source of application errors. Almost all modern Java applications use DataSource implementations (and pooling DataSources are very common) rather than simple JDBC connections.